# Lag on javascript scroll - Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scroll, lag, parallax

I'm trying to change the background-positition & top property when the user scrolls. I want to simulate a fixed position for background and parallax for sprite so I've done the following :

**HTML part**

```
<section id="first" data-type="background" data-speed="1">
    <div id="sprite1" data-type="sprite" data-speed="-1.5"></div>
    <div id="sprite2" data-type="sprite" data-speed="-1"></div>
</section>
<section id="second" data-type="background" data-speed="1">

</section>
```

**CSS part**

```
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    position: relative;
}

#first {
   background: url('../img/bg1.png'), no-repeat, fixed, 50% 0;
}

#second {
    background: url('../img/bg2.png'), no-repeat, fixed, 50% 0;
}

#sprite1 {
    position: relative;
    background: url('../img/sprite1.png'), no-repeat, fixed, 50% 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 550px;
    left: 100px;
}

#sprite2 {
    position: relative;
    background: url('../img/sprite2.png'), no-repeat, fixed, 50% 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 650px;
    left: 150px;
}
```

**JS part**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Initialisation */
    var $window = $(window);

    var offset = 0;
    $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        console.log($this);
        $this.data('data', {
            height: $this.height() + offset,
            speed: parseFloat($this.attr('data-speed'))
        });
        offset = $this.data('data').height;
    });

    $('div[data-type="sprite"]').each(function(index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('data', {
                xPosition: parseInt($this.css('top').replace(/px/, '')),
            yPosition: parseInt($this.css('left').replace(/px/, '')),
            speed: parseFloat($this.attr('data-speed'))
        });
        console.log($this.data('data'));
    });

    $('#first').data('position', '0');
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        console.log($(this));
        var scrollPos = parseInt($window.scrollTop());
        $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(index) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.css('background-position', '50% ' + (scrollPos / $this.data('speed') + $this.data('data').height) + 'px');
        });
        $('div[data-type="sprite"]').each(function(index) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.css('top', ((scrollPos / $this.data('data').speed) + $this.data('data').xPosition) + 'px');
        });
    });

});
```

You can see the result [here](http://pcreations.fr/labs/)

On Firefox there is no problem, backgrounds seems fixed, but on Chrome, it seems that the browser starts by scrolling the page and after executes the code. So it's totally jerked on Chrome...
Is there any way to force code execution before page scrolling ?

Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are refering to in the scrolling animation, I just guess. Instead of using $.css() you could start using $.animate() to make the transitions smoother. I've also checked this in IE and it also seems to do the same. When using $.animate() instead of $.css then $.scroll() that might be registered differently throughout multiple browsers might get smoothened away.

Comment: Hi, thx for answer ! Actually my issue is not refering to scrolling animation but to "jerking" background effect when user scrolls. Look at the top of blank square, it seems that Chrome scrolls page first and after executes the callback. It's the expected behavior by definition of what callback it is but in Chrome there is very poor performance resulting in displaying first the page scroll and after executes the changement of background-position. IMO the problem is here and that's why it's jerking but i'm pretty surprised of this behavior...